# Command works in ex mode but not during init (call)

Tags: vimrc, neovim

When I run this command in `ex` mode it works without a problem:

```
:call deoplete#custom#source('ultisnips', 'rank', 1000)
```

However, when I put it in my vimrc I get an error:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/me/config/nvim/plugins/deoplete.vim:
line   14:
E117: Unknown function: deoplete#custom#source
```

I have the deoplete plugin installed via a git submodule and deoplete works in vim.  I just can't use `call` with any of its commands.  Am using Neovim 0.3.3.  I feel perhaps my init is being sourced before the plugin has finished loading but I am not sure how to go about sorting this out.

Comment: Where is the plugin located? If it’s in packpath, in wont be loaded until after your vimrc is loaded.

Comment: They are in `site/pack/me/start/**` - is there somewhere else they should be ?

Comment: Thats the right spot. I’ll add an answer addressing packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OP, the plugin directory is located inside the `'packpath'`, which means the plugin is not available until *after* the vimrc is processed:

> ```
> When Vim starts up, after processing your .vimrc, it scans all directories in
> 'packpath' for plugins under the "pack/*/start" directory.  First all those
> directories are added to 'runtimepath'.  Then all the plugins are loaded.
> See |packload-two-steps| for how these two steps can be useful.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> Note that the files under "pack/foo/opt" are not loaded automatically, only the
> ones under "pack/foo/start".  See |pack-add| below for how the "opt" directory
> is used.
> Loading packages automatically will not happen if loading plugins is disabled,
> see |load-plugins|.
> To load packages earlier, so that 'runtimepath' gets updated: >
>     :packloadall
> This also works when loading plugins is disabled.  The automatic loading will
> only happen once.
> ```
>
> (`:help packages`)

While the help system mentions using `:packloadall` to load packages earlier, I offer an alternative suggestion: the `after` directory. By the time after files load, packages have been loaded. In [my own Dotfiles](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/tree/master/links/vim/after/plugin/config), I keep a directory `~/.vim/after/plugin/config/`<sup>1</sup> with short files to customize my plugins.

As an example, my config for ale is in `~/.vim/after/plugin/config/ale.vim`:

```
if ! exists(':ALEInfo')
  finish
endif

let g:ale_set_signs = 0

let g:ale_linters = {
      \ 'python': 'all',
      \ 'java': [],
      \ }
```

The trick is generally to find a reliable way of testing for the presence of the plugin: when they define commands or "skip" variables (e.g. `g:loaded_{name}`), we can test those. Autoload'ed functions (`file#name`) are harder because they don't exist until they are used.

In your case, I'd use [`g:loaded_deoplete`](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim/blob/master/plugin/deoplete.vim) in a file like `~/.vim/after/plugin/config/deoplete.vim` (use the equivalent for neovim):

```
if ! exists('g:loaded_deoplete')
  finish
endif

" your custom code here
call deoplete#custom#source('ultisnips', 'rank', 1000)
```

---

1. The name `plugin` does not mean *plugin* as a set of code from GitHub or elsewhere, but rather a plugin script (cf. `:help plugin`). The name `config` is not significant except that it helps me organize my `after/plugin` directory: all the configuration lies there. Note that all subdirectories of a plugin directory are searched for scripts.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed response - I think the `after\plugin` folder seems a more canonical way to do things and now that I've moved everything around I like it much better.  I guess it would make sense to move all my plugin related business in there, come to think of it!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [`VimEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) autocmd:

```
augroup DeopleteOptions
   au!
   autocmd VimEnter * 
   \ if exists('*deoplete#custom#source') | 
   \     call deoplete#custom#source('ultisnips', 'rank', 1000) |
   \ endif
augroup END
```

The `if` avoids errors if you are running somewhere you don't have all your plugins installed.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response!  The `if` statement trips it up though for me ... if I remove it and just call: `autocmd VimEnter * call deoplete#custom#source('ultisnips', 'rank', 1000)` it works  ... I tried to play around with variations but can't figure out what is wrong with that if statement.

Comment: @thornomad glad I could help! Have you tried to uninstall the plugin (or at least rename the autoload folder)? It is supposed to make no difference if you have the `deoplete` plugin installed. But if you copy your vimrc to a server to do some quick work without installing your plugins then you would keep receiving annoying errors every time you open neovim.

Comment: The if wont work because autoloaded functions arent defined until first-called.

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble, you are right. OP could try `if &rtp =~ 'plugin-name`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178537/717124).